# Retrieving a Golang struct from a C void pointer

Tags: go, cgo

I have a C struct that looks something like this:

```
struct room {
    void *reset_first;
}
```

I have a Golang struct that looks something like this:

```
type reset struct {
    command string
}
```

Thanks to the joys of cgo, I can do the following from Go:

```
func someStuff(a *C.room, b *reset) {
    a.reset_first = unsafe.Pointer(b)
}
```

and all is well

Then I attempt to retrieve it later:

```
func otherStuff(a *C.room) {
    var r = (*reset)(a.reset_first)
    fmt.Println(r.command)
}
```

and I end up with a segfault:

```
Thread 12 "test" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
316                                     fmt.Println(r.command)
```

but some of the values I get from inspection with gdb surprise me:

```
(gdb) info args
a = 0x7fffd5bc2d48
(gdb) info locals
r = 0x5
(gdb) print a
$1 = (struct main._Ctype_struct_room *) 0x7fffd5bc2d48
(gdb) print b
$2 = (struct main.reset *) 0x5
(gdb) print *a
3 = {_type = 2, _ = "\000\000\000", reset_first = 0xc422224a80}
```

How does `r` end up as `0x5` not `0xc422224a80`?

I'm not surprised that trying to dereference 5 results in a segfault, but I'm baffled as to where the 5 came from!

Comment: If you are calling `go` from `c`, then it is not valid, one shouldn't send any go pointers to `c`, until and unless `go` is calling `c`, which in-turn calls `go`, `go->c->go`, `c->go` will not work.[here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

Comment: Ah. Yes. Thank you! Want to stick that as an answer so I can accept it please?